# What does "forceCompile" mean on YII when you use Less?

Tags: yii

I have this:

```
'components'=>array(
  'less'=>array(
    'class'=>'ext.less.components.LessCompiler',
    'forceCompile'=> true, //YII_DEBUG, // indicates whether to force compiling
    //'compress'=>false, // indicates whether to compress compiled CSS
    //'debug'=>false, // indicates whether to enable compiler debugging mode
    'paths'=>array(
      'less/style.less'=>'css/style.css',
    ),
  ),
```

If I enable forceCompile my site is extremely slow. I would imagine because it regenerates the css on each page load. My question is around disabling it. If I disable it:

1. Will any changes I make to style.less not reflect in the browser?
2. If so, what is the point of Less? Surely it can't actually be used in production then? Or do you disable forceCompile so it only generates it once?

Any clarity on forceCompile would be highly appreciated!

(And yes, I looked all of for a clear explanation... best I could find was [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26348-extension-less/)).

Comment: point of less, as in point of less the language or less the extension?

Comment: Both. Less the extension implements less? Why do you ask? (think I'm missing the point of your question....)

Comment: less the lang, is definitely used in production also. the ext is your choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me tell you what is the point of [less](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/less/info):

1. less is a [meta language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage), so in general terms using less helps you write **easily maintainable css**, although the "*language*" used is less syntax. As a common example, you can define variables in less that are compiled to css values according to the other *statements* in your less file. Or you can use mixins, nesting, inheritance concepts like you would in most other languages that support OOP.
2. So you write understandable, **readable** *pseudo/meta css* code that is converted to actual css upon compilation.

---

Now the extension:

Even if you disable `forceCompile`, the changes made in *style.less* should reflect, because the extension checks if the file was modified (the following lines from *LessCompiler.php* should convince you about that):

```
if ($this->forceCompile || $this->hasChanges())
    $this->compileAll();

// ...

/**
 * Returns whether any of files configured to be compiled has changed.
 * @return boolean the result.
 */
protected function hasChanges() {
    // ...
        $compiled = $this->getLastModified($destination);
    // ...
        $modified = $this->getLastModified($dir);
    // ...
}

/**
 * Returns the last modified for a specific path.
 * @param string $path the path.
 * @return integer the last modified (as a timestamp).
 */
protected function getLastModified($path){ 
    //...
}
```

So `forceCompile` will always compile the file(s) you specify in `paths`, and you should not enable it in production. The `hasChanges` call should take care of *less files that have been modified*, and compile them, which as you see above is automatically done by the extension.